# Is there a shortcut to windows task scheduler that works in all windows versions?

Tags: windows, scheduled-tasks

I would like to put a link to windows task scheduler in an application, so user can get to it easily.

The link in windows 7 is `%windir%\system32\taskschd.msc /s`, but will this work in other versions?

Comment: Sorry, but, I have to ask the question.  Why would you want to force a user to deal with the task scheduler which is not easy to work with?  Wouldn't it make more sense for you to collect the information and schedule the task for them?

Comment: By user I mean a technical user. Sometimes tasks don't run for various reasons, for instance a user changing their password, and using the task scheduler UI is the last resort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works on all versions of Windows from Windows 2000 on.